# pass other form elements to ajax suggestion box script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

** moved to here:
[numerous similar AJAX suggestion boxes without ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206904/numerous-similar-ajax-sugestion-boxes-without-ids)

---

I paid somebody to build me a jQuery AJAX suggestion box script a while back.  It works great.  Now I'm trying to learn about it enough to modify it to do something different.

Right now, the script that generates the suggestions just takes the query text and does the same check every time.  Now, I want to be able to pass along additional info so different things are looked for with each instance of a search box.

The HTML...  simple, obvious.

```
<input class="suggest" name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

The jQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

    $('.suggest').autocomplete(
    {

        source:'output.php', minLength:3,

        focus: function (event, ui) 
        {
          $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
          return false;
        }

    }
    );


[snip]

}
```

Instead of:

```
source:'output.php', minLength:3,
```

I'd like:

```
source:'output.php?arg1=blah1&arg2=blah2', minLength:3,
```

where arg1 and arg2 are passed along in the form...

```
<input class="suggest" name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" />

<input type="hidden" name="arg1" value="blah1" />

<input type="hidden" name="arg2" value="blah2" />
```

Does this make sense?

Thanks guys.  I know just about "this much" about OOL's and javascript, so I'm learning...

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

update

these don't work...

// source:'/suggest/?q='+\$('input[name=q]').val(), minLength:3,

// source:'/suggest/?q='+\$('input[type="text"][name="q"]').val(), minLength:3,

// source:'/suggest/?q='+\$('input[type="text"]').val(), minLength:3,

// source:'/suggest/?q='+\$('input:text').val(), minLength:3,

// source:'/suggest/?q='+\$('input[type=text]').val(), minLength:3,

... but this does...

```
    source:'/suggest/?q='+'alex', minLength:3,
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get away with using jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. The documentation states that it will:

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

Which sounds like what you're looking to do. You can try something like this:

```
$('.suggest').autocomplete({
    source:'output.php?' + $("#MY_FORM_ID").serialize(), minLength:3,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
      $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Please note that using a string as the `source` will not cause the URL to change dynamically with the value of the input. To do that, you'll need to use a callback function and facilitate the request/response yourself. The code I show above will use the value of `MY_FORM_ID` at the time the autocomplete widget is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('.suggest').autocomplete({
    source:'output.php?arg1='+$('input[name=arg1]').val()+'&arg2='+$('input[name=arg2]').val(), minLength:3,
});
```

Comment: I tried this...  (see edit to original post)   I must be leaving something out...