# numerous similar AJAX suggestion boxes without ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box on my site that uses autocomplete to give suggestions, and it works great.  Now I want to use it on several INPUT fields on a single page.  However, the script uses ID tags to access the contents of the INPUT form box.

I modified this:

`$('#suggest').autocomplete(`

to this:

`$('.suggest').autocomplete(`

How do I access the INPUT box text now that I lose the ability to use `getElementsById`?

Comment: Since you're asking for procedural tips, etc -- I would suggest trimming down your question significantly. There seems to be a lot of irrelevant information included here. You can do this by removing background information and by trying to distill problems to single bite-sized questions.

Comment: Thanks David...  I reposted the question.

Comment: Where is it that you want to access the input in question? When the user selected a word? When the user started typing something? Or when the user clicked in a suggest-input? Or someplace different altogether?

Comment: jQuery is pushing the input box text to the script that is fetching the suggestions by doing this: source:'/suggest/?q='+$('input[name=q]').val(), minLength:3,     ... but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I know what you're asking. You have several `input` elements on a page, none of which have `id` attributes, but *do* have `name` attributes. Each `input` has a separate `autocomplete` widget attached to it, and you want to query a URL as your data source, passing in the `name` if the `input` being interacted with.

Ok.

I set up a fiddle to do what I'm describing above, which I think is what you want. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4GXAm/1/

The magic is here:

```
$(".example").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var url = "/suggest/?" + $(this.element).serialize();

        alert("perform an AJAX request with " + url);

        // Respond with the ajax results
        response(["a", "b", "c"]);
    }
});
```

Using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will get you a name/value pair from the input, without needing to know its `id` or `name` attribute. You can get the element being interacted with by using `$(this.element)` when using a callback function as your autocomplete source.

I recommend looking at an example of the [autocomplete that uses a callback function as a remote data source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) for more details.

Comment: Yes.  Yes, yes, yes.  YES!!!!!!!!!!!!  I'll play with this tomorrow, but the answer is YES, your assessment is right and it looks like it works perfectly.  That's it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexCalder I'm glad to hear it :). If it does indeed solve your issue feel free to mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI autocomplete plugin should do the trick for you. This seems to be a scrap of what you were trying to use before, but reading the documentation should get you through it a bit better:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Just make sure to:

- include the scripts and stylesheets for jquery ui on your page
- make good use of $(this) to refer to the element that is being worked with. The above example is selecting all text inputs.

If you are still confused after this, I'd be glad to give more specific guidance if you can cut most of the explanation here and provide us with the actual code that isn't working, but as long as you understand the $(this) concept, I think this should get you what you need.

Comment: Looked at the link...  Looks like the guy who did the existing script used exactly this...   Thanks for this, good to save.  I just edited the question.  Can you give it another look?  Thanks Jeff.